# How to pass property to JVM without using -D syntax?

Tags: java, properties, environment-variables

I need to pass properties to a java execution without using the -D syntax, is it possible?

Normally I run:

```
java -DrandomProperty=randomVal MyPackage.MyClass
```

But now, I cannot pass properties to the java command (I have no access to the actual call because it's nested) and I can neither pass them as environment variables (I do not have access to MyPackage.MyClass sources and thus I can't replace System.getProperty("randomProperty") calls with System.getenv("randomProperty").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to set the environmental variable `_JAVA_OPTIONS`. The JVM reads this environmental variable to get the default JVM parameters to start with. Setting the `_JAVA_OPTIONS` to `-DrandomProperty=randomVal` will cause all JVMs to start as though the flag was passed into the command line.

http://progexc.blogspot.co.uk/2013/12/what-i-discovered-while-trying-to-pass.html

Comment: Thank you! tomorrow I'll try it an accept your answer if it does work in my case